# How is the meaning of preceding derived from "en- 'in, on'" and following from "pro-"?

Tags: meaning, prefixes

> en·clit·ic [enˈklidik, inˈklidik] noun enclitic (noun) · enclitics
> (plural noun) a word pronounced with so little emphasis that it is
> shortened and forms part of the **preceding** word, e.g., n't in can't.
> Compare with proclitic
>
> enclitic (adjective) denoting or relating to an enclitic.
>
> Origin mid 17th century: via late Latin from Greek enklitikos, from
> enklinein ‘lean on’, from **en- ‘in, on’** + klinein ‘to lean’.

and

> pro·clit·ic [prōˈklidik] noun proclitic (noun) · proclitics (plural
> noun) a word pronounced with so little emphasis that it is shortened
> and forms part of the **following** word, for example, you in y'all.
> Compare with enclitic
>
> proclitic (adjective) denoting or relating to a proclitic.
>
> Origin early 19th century: from modern Latin procliticus, from **pro-** +
> -cliticus (in late Latin encliticus: see enclitic).

I was wondering how the meaning of preceding is derived from "en- 'in, on'" and following from "pro-"?

Would the meanings be clearer if the prefixes were something else, such as "pre-" or "post-"?

Comment: Are you asking why 'en' contrasts with 'pro' in the key term here? One seems to get absorbed **in** the preceding word. The other seems to push **forward** to the next word. Otherwise, asking for consistency in English is often optimistic.

Comment: ***pro*** in Latin is "earlier, before", and proclitics ('t' in "t-shirt") attach to the ***beginning*** of a host word. The full OED just says ***enclitic*** ('n't' in "can't") is from Latin ***encliticus***, with no further breakdown. But I never knew either of these subcategories until today. Prof John Lawler always just called them all ***clitics***, so far as I recall. Strangely, though, the full OED has ***enclitic*** from 1656, and ***proclitic*** from 1803, but plain ***clitic*** didn't appear until 1946.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments from @yosefbaskin and @fumblefingers answer the direct question.

Let me just add, it can be intellectually amusing to debate the origins of a word and how the meaning is derived from components of the word. But ultimately, arguing that a word should have been constructed differently is unproductive. Even if you and I agreed that it should be "preclitic" and "postclitic", the academic world is not going to say, "Hey, we'd better change all the dictionaries now, because two random people on a forum said they have a better idea!" It takes a long time and the right circumstances for a new word to be accepted. Demanding that it be changed because you don't think it makes sense is a quixotic quest. I wouldn't bother except in rare cases where I think the choice of a word propagates a false or offensive idea.